# Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final But works independently

Tags: java, lambda

I have a Constants variable defined as final as seen below:

```
Constants.java

public static final List<Integer> SPECIAL_CASE = Arrays.asList (2, 3, 6, 7);
```

Its an Integer list of values. I have a service layer with following code:

```
ReportServiceImpl.java
public class ReportServiceImpl
{
/////////

Report repObj = new Report();
BeanUtils.copyProperties(repPending, repObj);
..........


//////
if(Constants.SPECIAL_CASE.stream().anyMatch(element ->repObj.getSpecialCase() == element)) {
System.out.println("It is a  Special report...");
}

if((Constants.SPECIAL_CASE.stream().anyMatch(element -> repObj.getSpecialCase() == element))
        || ((repObj.getMp() == null || repObj.getMp() == 0)
        && (repObj.getMPro() == null || repObj.getMPro() == 0))
){

// do something
.....
...//
}


/////////
}
```

If you look at how the object is formed its coming from another object and BeanUtils copies from one object to another. Im using the new object for if condition.
The 1st if checks if the repObj.getSpecialCase() macths with Integer list and it works fine. No issues the sysout gets printed. Next I am adding the same condition in the 2nd if loop inaddition to other conditions and im getting a red on the code with `"Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final"`

Im not sure why the 1st if works and repObj on the 2nd if shows this error. The class doesnt compile. Any input on why this happens and how to handle this exception. Thank you so much.

Comment: "same condition"? `repPending` is not the same as `repObj` - but posted code seems incomplete, we cannot see what else is happening with that variables - `repObj` being changed later on ?!? - better include a [mre]

Comment: Please read [mre]

Comment: @user85421
My bad its repObj on both places. Corrected the code above

Comment: Change `Report repObj = new Report()` to `final Report repObj = new Report()`.  What happens?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman Yes that got rid of the error. But what if i need to change the object moving back and forth with the method? Will it impact something else if I make it final?

Comment: Then you'll have to do something else, like make a final copy of the variable, or use a different variable for the parts that change.